# jQuery location picker API location name field is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery location picker API for map view. Everything in that API working fine except when we give input for location name it doesn't work. And also autocomplete option not working and map not show the location.

```
Location: <input type="text" id="location" style="width: 200px"/>
Lat <input type="text" id="lat" style="width: 200px"/>
Long: <input type="text" id="lng" style="width: 200px"/>
<div id="us2" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>   

<script>$('#us2').locationpicker({
location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},   
radius: 0,
inputBinding: {
    latitudeInput: $('#lat'),
    longitudeInput: $('#lng'),
    locationNameInput: $('#location')
},
 enableAutocomplete: true,
 onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
  alert("");
 }
 });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turns out that you need to enable "Google Places API Web Service" in the google developer console if you are using the Google Maps API with an API key. After I did this, the autocomplete worked.

Comment: Thank you so much nfilmer it working .We tried this for one week but we not found the issue.your comment helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it occurs since the DOM is not yet loaded once the location picker is initialized.

Try to invoke location picker initialization as shown below:

```
$(function() {


  $('#us2').locationpicker({
   location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},   
   radius: 0,
   inputBinding: {
      latitudeInput: $('#lat'),
      longitudeInput: $('#lng'),
      locationNameInput: $('#location')
   },
   enableAutocomplete: true,
   onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
      alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
    }
  });


});
```

**[Demo (Plunker)](https://plnkr.co/edit/mfiPLrChUShIMLvpqjHI?p=preview)**

Comment: hi vadim,thanks for your comment but this script is not working only in server.we tried your code but it is not working.